setIdleTimeout and setKeepaliveTime are not working with MySQL wait_timeout
Scenario 1:
Spring Boot 2.6.3
HikariConfig hikariConfig = new HikariConfig();
hikariConfig.setDriverClassName(dataSourceProperties.getDriver());
hikariConfig.setUsername(dataSourceProperties.getUsername());
hikariConfig.setPassword(dataSourceProperties.getPassword());
hikariConfig.setJdbcUrl(jdbcUrl);
hikariConfig.setMaximumPoolSize(1);
hikariConfig.setMinimumIdle(0);
hikariConfig.setIdleTimeout(5000); //5 Seconds
return new HikariDataSource(hikariConfig);

MySQL 8
wait_timeout = 30 //30 Seconds
As my understanding HikariCP with Spring Boot and MySQL 8, the ideal connection should be removed after 5 seconds, when I check PROCESSLIST in the MySQL it is alive for 30 seconds which is the wait_timout of the MySQL connection.
Scenario 2:
hikariConfig.setKeepaliveTime(40000); //40 Seconds
The connection should be alive for 40 seconds but removed in 30 seconds which is the wait_timout of the MySQL connection.
I was testing how HikariCP handles idle connections in two scenarios with Spring Boot 2.6.3 and MySQL 8, configured as follows:
Scenario 1:

HikariCP idleTimeout set to 5 seconds.
MySQL wait_timeout set to 30 seconds.

I expected HikariCP to remove idle connections after 5 seconds. However, when I checked the MySQL PROCESSLIST, the connections remained active for 30 seconds, matching the MySQL wait_timeout.
Scenario 2:

HikariCP keepaliveTime set to 40 seconds.
MySQL wait_timeout still 30 seconds.

I expected the connections to stay alive for 40 seconds due to the keepaliveTime configuration. Instead, they were closed after 30 seconds, respecting MySQL's wait_timeout.
I would like to understand why HikariCP behaves this way and how these configurations interact with MySQL's wait_timeout.
